# Refresh JComboBox with SwingX AutoCompleteDecorator

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, swingx

I am using SwingX AutoCompleteDecorator on a JComboBox. Everything works fine except I would like my user to be allowed to change the name of my object, name that is also displayed in the combobox. The problem is that I can refresh my combobox but the displayed string from the autocomplete decorator remains the same as shown in the picture:
[image: Problem]

The code to refresh the combobox looks like this:

```
try {
   Aannemer a = getNewAannemer();
   MainController.getInstance().updateAannemer(a);
   aannemerBox.revalidate();
   aannemerBox.repaint();
} catch (Exception ex) {
   //...
}
```

The string updates when I reselect the object from the combobox.
I also tried using a personalised renderer and editor for the combobox.

Any ideas how i can also refresh the string shown in the combobox?

Answer (score 0):

With the current code, it is hard to tell what is going wrong. The following code works just fine for me

```
import org.jdesktop.swingx.autocomplete.AutoCompleteDecorator;

import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

public class AutoCompleteCombobox {

  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame( "TestFrame" );

      JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<>(  );
      DefaultComboBoxModel<String> model = new DefaultComboBoxModel<>(  );
      model.addElement( "First" );
      model.addElement( "Second" );
      comboBox.setModel( model );
      comboBox.setEditable( true );

      AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate( comboBox );

      frame.getContentPane().add( comboBox );

      JButton button = new JButton( "Add item" );
      button.addActionListener( e -> {
        String selectedItem = ( String ) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
        if ( comboBox.getSelectedIndex() == -1 ){
          model.addElement( selectedItem );
        }
      } );
      frame.getContentPane().add( button, BorderLayout.SOUTH );

      frame.pack();
      frame.setVisible( true );
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
    } );
  }
}
```

- Auto-complete works as expected
- I can input new items
- When using the add button, I can add the new item and the autocomplete behaves nicely

In short, I cannot reproduce your issue. Please post a piece of code in your question which allows us to reproduce the problem.